# When trying to output an integer, to a file it outputs an array of numbers

Tags: c, windows

I'm writing a function that will give the user an option to choose an item from a list.
When an option is chosen it should then call a dedicated function to ask for the quantity of the item and then output it to a file. Below are the two functions.

```
void pos2()
 {
    int choice;
    printf("\n Enter The item : ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    switch (choice) {
    case 1:
        apple();
        break;

    case 2:
       editInventory();
        break;


    case 3:

        printf("\n Returning... \n\n");
        printf("Returning in 3 seconds...\n");
        Sleep(3000);
        system("cls");
        printMenu();


    default:
        system("cls");
        printf("\ninvalid choice Try again \n");
        printMenu();
    }
}

    void apple()
{
        FILE*out=fopen("pos.txt","w");
        int amt;
        printf("Apple Choosen\n");
        printf("Enter the Amount\n");
        scanf("%d",&amt);
        fprintf(out,"%d",&amt);
}
```

In this case, the user is only able to choose 1 at the moment which will ask them to enter the number of apples, and then enter, it would save the value to a text file called pos.txt. When I do enter an amount it appears I'm given the address value or some sort of array in return. This is the output in the text file:

> 6421716

if anyone can offer assistance or guide me in the right direction that would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: `fprintf(out,"%d",&amt);` remove `&`. Your compiler should be warning you about that, look up how to turn on all warnings.

Comment: I didn't get any warning unfortunately. I will do that now, Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Great News, @Passerby (https://stackoverflow.com/users/17196203/passerby) commented the solution under my Question.

The issue here was the `&` in my `fprintf(out,"%d",&amt);` which was causing the weird number to be outputted. Thanks once again to everyone helping me solve this and a special thanks to @Passerby for the solution.